# how to send mail to localhost

Tags: java, email, smtp, localhost

I am using smtp protocol to send email via gmail . I want to send mail to localhost . What address I will give for localhost to get that email ?

Comment: Well address for localhost is localhost. But it wont work because first you need to have an smtp server to recieve email. Eevn if you install one, the gmail servers would need to know about its presence - which will be difficult for you to set up unless you sign up for a domain name. Let us know how you want to proceed and we'll offer further help.

Comment: That depends on whether `localhost` is running an SMTP server, you know a valid e-mail address on that server and there is no load balancing or higher priority MX records for that domain that would cause your e-mail to be directed to another server instead. Even if you open port 25 on localhost rather than going via gmail, and communicate with the localhosts smtp server directly, you will need to know the answers to some of these questions for your e-mail not to be rejected. Please clarify what you want to do and why you want to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is localhost in this case? Your local desktop or a server?

The only way gmail is going to be able to send mail to it, is if you've got an SMTP server running there and it has an IP that's accessible from the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can only send to localhost from a mail server running on localhost. Generally though you'd need an Internet domain for this instead.